# How can i delete this text from the screen "There weren't any photos taken at this date with a mars rover" when there is a photo taken on that date

Tags: javascript

When i choose a date and there isn't a photo taken for that date. I return a message to the screen stating that there is no photo for that date. However, if I go and choose a different date where there is a photo, the screen refreshes and the text "There weren't any photos taken at this date with a mars rover" is still on the screen with the photo. How do i delete this text for when there is a photo for the specific date the user chose?

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getFetch);

function getFetch() {
  const choice = document.querySelector('input').value.trim();

  if (!choice) {
    console.error('No date selected');
    return;
  }

  const apiKey = '[REDACTED]';
  const url = `https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?                

      earth_date=${choice}&api_key=${apiKey}`;

  fetch(url).then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error('ERROR');
    }
    return res.json();
  }).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.photos && data.photos.length > 0) {
      const photo = data.photos[0];
      document.querySelector('.yo').src = photo.img_src;
      document.querySelector('h3').innerText = photo.camera.full_name;
      document.querySelector('h2').innerText = photo.earth_date;
    } else {
      document.querySelector('h4').innerText = "There weren't any photos taken at this date with a   

      mars rover "
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error('Prob with fetch', err);
  });
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('h4').innerText=""` in the "if" block?